# Home router blocking outbound SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, vpn, vagrant

TL;DR I can't SSH to customer's server on customer's VPN from my home but I can from the office.

I'm using MacOS and when I'm in the office I can:

1. Start a vagrant box on my computer.
2. Use VPNC to join that vagrant image to a customer's VPN.
3. SSH into the customer's servers within that VPN.

But when I take my work computer home I can only do steps 1. and 2. but not step 3.

Observations:

1. Other colleagues can complete step 3. from their own homes without the customer configuring anything extra.
2. After step 1. and 2. at home I can ping the target server in step 3. so I don't think the customer's security config is blocking my home address. I can get on the VPN and then to the customer my IP is a 10.0.0x/VPN IP - the customer's server doesn't see that I'm at home.
3. running `ssh user@server` just hangs forever.
4. If I go via Settings->Networks and use MacOS's own VPN tool to place my whole computer on the VPN (as opposed to just the vagrant box) then I *can* ssh to the customer's server.

I thought that perhaps my router is somehow blocking the outgoing ssh connection but I don't have any rules blocking outbound connections. Also, looking at point 4. above perhaps there's something in the VPN config on my vagrant box I should look at but AFAIK it's the same as for my colleagues.

Anyone out there have any ideas what's preventing me from SSH'ing from home?

UDPATE

Output of running `ssh -vvvv 10.0.0.20`:

```
vagrant@deployer:~$ ssh -vvvv 10.0.0.20
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.20 [10.0.0.20] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.0.0.20" from file "/home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

Comment: Look through your router's advanced settings for VPN related items.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I also thought maybe the router's blocking the VPN but I can't see anything which might block VPN traffic. Also, I can connect to the VPN and I can SSH over the VPN as long as my whole computer is on the VPN.

Comment: Ahhh I missed fact 4 of the question. Sorry.

Comment: I am not familiar with Vagrant but most VM hosts have different network configurations, for example in a VirtualBox VM I have issues with some VPNs using the default NAT configuration, but if I change the VM's network adapter to Bridged mode, it works fine. Just throwing that out there.